# jquery ajax tabs change to "Loading..." after clicking on them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the following code all of the tabs initially display their proper text (Home,Reports,Setup,Documentation,Support).  When any of the ajax tabs are clicked (Home, Documentation, Support) the text on the tab changes to "Loading...".  However,  the 2 non ajax tabs (Reports and Setup) keep their text.   How do I keep it from going to "Loading..."  Why would this change?

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs({ ajaxOptions: {cache: false}});
    }
</script>
    <html>
    <div id="tabs">
    <div id="menu">
         <ul>
        <li><a href="home.php" title=Home><span>Home</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#report_tabs" title=Reports><span>Reports</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#setup_tabs" title=Setup><span>Setup</span></a></li> 
             <li><a href="documentation.php" title=Documentation><span>Documentation</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="support.php" title=Support><span>Support</span></a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to do. Do you want the non-ajax tabs to read "Loading..." on click or do you want the ajax tabs to not read "Loading..." on click?

Comment: @SimpleCoder nick nailed it. The loading... text just stayed there. It wouldn't go back to normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`spinner` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-spinner) to `false`, or an empty string, like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ 
  ajaxOptions: {cache: false},
  spinner: false
});
```

You can see the [`if(o.spinner)`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#L624) check here, either of these will fail this check, avoiding the replacement (as will other data types, but `false` is the clearest intention IMO).